# LEFT JOIN discarding left rows in results?

Tags: google-bigquery

Simplifying my issue, let's say I have two tables:

1. "Users" storing user_id and event_date from users who access each day.
2. "Purchases" storing user_id, event_date and product_id from users who make purchases each day.

I need to get from all users, their respective product purchases, or null value for product_id if a user didn't make a purchase. For that purpose I made this query:

```
with all_users as (
  select user_id from `my_project.my_dataset.Users`
  where event_date = "2019-12-01"
)

select user_id,product_id
from all_users
left join `my_project.my_dataset.Purchases`
  using(user_id)
where event_date = "2019-12-01"
```

But this query returns only user_id who made purchases, in other words, there are rows in the LEFT from_item (all_users) that are being ommited in the result.

Is this working as spected? I read that [LEFT JOIN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#left-outer-join) always retains all rows of the left from_item.

**EDIT 1:**
Adding some screenshots:
This is the full query detailed before, but with real names (table "Users" is "user_metrics_daily" and table "Purchases" is "virtual_currency_daily"). As you can see, I added the `count(distinct user_pseudo_id)OVER()` to count how many distinct users are in the result.

[image]

In the other hand, this is a query to get the number of users I expect to have in the result (8935 users, with null values in product_id for users who don't purchase). But actually I got 2724 distinct users (the number of users who made purchases).
[image]

**EDIT 2:** I found a **solution** to my desired result, but still I don't understand what's wrong with my first query.
[image]

Comment: Left join does what you think; the error is somewhere else. My bet is that you are expecting to see users that you initially filtered out in the `with` clause by specificing an event_date.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis filtering by event_date is not the problem. Let's say this filter returns 1000 users in "all_users" query. So I expect to see 1000 users in the final query result, after the left join, but not. I'm just seeing users who made purchases, let's say.. 50 users.

Comment: @alek6dj please provide screenshots as it's hard to believe this, we might catch an error in your query

Comment: @alek6dj, in your code you can specify from which table you are retrieving user_id with a alias. Can you do that and check if your output changes?

Comment: @Pentium10 Added screenshots

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes It's the same output

Comment: Your understanding of how left join should work is correct. Also, can you  filter the results only for users who did not purchase ? In the WHERE statement, so we can explore what is happening.

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes Take a look to "Edit 2", maybe you can understand what happended in my first query...

Comment: I see that now in your last query you specify the table name from where the user_id column should come from. I think that is the reason.

Answer (score -1):

Your query (as it is) should return an error because `user_id` is ambiguous. BigQuery does not know if you want the column from `all_users` or `my_project.my_dataset.Purchases`.

Discarding that, you need to explicitly say from which table the projected columns should come from. In your case, `user_id` from `all_users` and `product_id` from `my_project.my_dataset.Purchases`.

```
with all_users as (
  select user_id from `my_project.my_dataset.Users`
  where event_date = "2019-12-01"
)

select
  a.user_id,
  p.product_id
from all_users as a
left join `my_project.my_dataset.Purchases` as p on a.user_id = p.user_id
where event_date = "2019-12-01"
```

Comment: The query is OK because I'm specifying that join is using user_id, so, that field isn't ambiguous. I also tried your suggestion and the result is the same I got.

Comment: I usually do not use `using` so I don't know if in this case it was doing a sort of `coalescence` on  `user_id`. When I said "ambiguous" user_id.

Comment: @alek6dj In fact if you write the query using `on a.user_id = p.user_id` instead of `using`. The SQL compiler gives you an error. So I thing that `using` will do a sort of `coalescence` of the two.

Comment: Also reading the docs about `using`, it said that return one column without specifying which one. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#using-clause